# How to use regex in jQuery :not() selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to match some IDs, but not any id that is a number. For example, I'd like to match `#about`, but not match `#67` or `#123`.

Here's my jQuery with a bit of regex. I think the regex is correct, but it's not getting parsed correctly as not any `href="#<number>"`

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"],[href="#\d+"])').click(function() { 
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
    || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
       if (target.length) {
         $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: target.offset().top -60
        }, 1500);
        return false;
    }
}
```

});

Is there some way I should be escaping that regex or inserting it as a variable or...?

Answer (score 0):

The jquery's selector doesn't support regex but you can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter anchors has specific `href` attribute using regex.

```js
$('a').filter(function(){
  return $(this).attr("href").match(/^#\D+$/);
}).css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">#</a>
<a href="#about">#about</a>
<a href="#67">#67</a>
<a href="#123">#123</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad, I get the filter part, but I can't figure out how to use the return value as the selector. I updated my code above to show the complete function.

Comment: @danzo Show relevant part of your html

Comment: This is a single WordPress page with anchor links such as #about and #contact. There are also some tabs on the page that are dynamically generated. Currently there are 3 tabs with IDs #67, #68, and #69, but there may be more in the future. I want the smooth scroll code above to ignore the dynamically generated IDs (i.e. IDs with numbers).

Comment: @danzo  This question is about **match `#about`, but not match `#67` or `#123`** and i answered to it. Your want (**smooth scroll code**) is new issue and you should ask new question.

Comment: @ mohammad It's not a new issue. You asked for my relevant HTML. Obviously I'm not going to post an entire page of html, so I just explained the usage.

Comment: Yes! Exactly! Thank you @mohammad!